# Solve $g(x + \frac{1}{x}) = x^y + \frac{1}{x^y}$

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, functional-equations

Let $y$ be a real number.

Find $g$ such that

$$g(x + \frac{1}{x}) = x^y + \frac{1}{x^y}$$

Is valid for all real $x$.

Comment: What did you try, what are your thoughts? $x+1/x=u$ is a quadratic equation in $x$, it should be trivial to find a form for $g(u)$.

Comment: Why close and downvote ?

Comment: Because your question is incomplete. You did not show your own efforts until the breaking point that you could not overcome. Usually, this place is not meant to solve your homework or arbitrary riddles, but to help with your specific problems in solving them.

Comment: It was not homework.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578246/about-fx-f-frac1x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $x=e^u$ one gets
$$g(2\cosh(u))=2\cosh(u·y)$$
which resolves to
$$
g(z)=2\cosh(y·\text{Arcosh}(z/2))
$$
for all $z\ge 2$

Comment: Thank you. Surprised i did not see that myself.